# why ButtonType isn't an enum in javafx

Tags: button, javafx, enums

I have tried to use a ButtonType variable in a switch statement only to discover that it's not an enum.

I somewhat realized that this was made to give the developer the ability to change the text of ButtonType, and ButtonType has ButtonData attribute which is an enum.

I want to ask, couldn't this ability to change text be possible with ButtonType being enum ? I'm thinking the developer only cares about the text that will be displayed in the UI, So a method `show(String whatthedeveloperwants)` on the enum would be enough I think , wouldn't it ?

Comment: And how would the developer get `whatthedeveloperwants` to the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question here, in my opinion, is promoted from "Can it be done?" to "Should it be done?". From the syntax point view what you propose is valid. You could have an enum for button type and have a method that would change the internal enum field responsible for UI text. However, from the concept point view it goes against the idea of an enumeration. From [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), an enum type represents a set of predefined constants. The idea of an enum element being a constant is consistent across many other languages. It conveys a message to developers, hence, one would expect a constant value, well, not change. If an instance of a type requires changing over time then you typically use a class mechanism. `ButtonType` can change, while `ButtonData` has predefined values and this has been captured by developers, so they use a class and enum respectively.

I doubt they have gone through the same chain of thoughts, but I believe they used the same principles when designing the API for `ButtonType`.